# NFS shares not being exported on reboot

Tags: ubuntu, nfs

When I reboot the NFS server (Ubuntu 14.04), it is not exporting the NFS shares (`sudo showmount -e` is empty). I have to open a terminal and manually `sudo exportfs -ra`. After that `showmount` will then display the correct information, and I am then able to mount the directory on the client, albeit manually.

Putting `exportfs -ra` into the global profile seems like a really hacky way to do it, and in anycase my other NFS servers (Ubuntu 12.04) don't seem to have this problem (but I did not set them up, I am just trying to integrtae this new one). Any ideas as to what could be happening? I can provide any extra info you'd like.

I have [another question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/754194/gui-doesnt-have-escalated-permissions-ubuntu-14-04-lightdm) open over at askubuntu that may be relevant.

Comment: I don't run ubuntu, so this is just a [guess](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo), but is this running: `service nfs-kernel-server status` ?

Comment: Yep: `nfsd running`